# How to echo anchor tag with query string?

Tags: php, html, mysql, anchor

I have this php code which has anchor tag with query string i.e.  ?attribute={$row1[\'att2\']}

In this the value $row1[\'att2\'] is not returning the database value of $row1['att2'] either because of using the escape character or because single-inverted comma is having a clash with the echo's single-inverted comma if we remove the escape character. How to solve this?

```
<?php 
  echo '<a href="example.php?attribute={$row1[\'att2\']}">'.$row1['att2'].'</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Why not do it the same as the other one: `echo '<a href="example.php?attribute='.$row1['att2'].'">'.$row1['att2'].'</a>';`

Comment: Also, depending on what is in that var you need to `urlencode($row1['att2'])`

Comment: php variables are not translated when put inside of a string with single quotes.

Comment: yup.got it.for query string i did not consider that option.

Answer (score 4):

What about the following code?

```
echo '<a href="example.php?attribute='.$row1['att2'].'">'.$row1['att2'].'</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep variable inside the string use double quotes.

```
echo "<a href=\"example.php?attribute={$row1['att2']}\">{$row1['att2']}</a>";
```

or

```
 echo '<a href="example.php?attribute=' . $row1['att2'] . '">' . $row1['att2'] . '</a>';
```

or

```
 echo sprintf('<a href="example.php?attribute=%1$s">%1$s</a>', (string)$row1['att2']);
```